# Advice with a file program asking for the largest number

Tags: file-io, python-3.x

the assignment this time around deals with using files. "Assume that a file containing a series of integers is named numbers.dat and exists on the computer's disk. Design a program that determines the largest number stored in the file. The instructor told us not to use array based implementations, and include a variable to count the number of items read from the file and output this count after displaying the largest value found in the file. I am having trouble on how to get the largest value without using array based implementation. Here is what I have so far:

```
    def main():
        n = 1
        largest = None

        num_input = int(input("How many numbers do " + "you have to input? "))

        numbers_file = open('numbers.dat', 'w')

        for count in range(1, num_input + 1):
            number = float(input('Enter the number #' + str(count) + ': '))

        if largest is None or n > largest:
            largest = n
        print('The largest value inputted is: ', largest)
        numbers_file.close()   
    main()
```

Comment: So what's the question?

Comment: The question is "how quickly can you do my homework?"

Comment: I don't know how to find the largest number and output it based upon what the user wrote in the file.

Comment: I have just edited the code, to incorporate finding the largest value, however the largest always returns 1

Answer (score 0):

Imagine you have a sheet of paper with hundreds of numbers on it. Using nothing but your brain and eyes, read those numbers and find the largest one.

How would you do this?

Now, how would you tell the computer to do it the same way?

Answer (score 0):

use a variable to store the current number and assume that it is largest. As you go through the file compare the stored number to current number from file, if number from file is greater store it in the variable else keep on reading the file. Repeat this until you reach end of the file.

```
 largest = 0;
 count = 0
 while ((num =input.readline()) != EOF) {
      count++;
      if (largest < num) {
           largest = num;
      }
   }
```