# How to make my program not an array/list but do the same as it should

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have recently started using python and I was wondering how to make my program have the same output without using array/lists. Basically, it opens a file containing numbers, and then prints the largest number as well as the amount of numbers within the file. I want to know how to convert my program into something that does not use array/list format.

```
def main():
    infile = open('numbers.dat', 'r')

    numbers = []
    for line in infile:
        numbers.append(int(line))
    infile.close()

    largest = max(numbers)
    print('The largest number in the file is: ',largest)

    count = len(numbers)
    print('The amount of numbers in the file is: ', count)
main()
```

Comment: This looks like the code in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15735892/largest-number-from-a-file-without-using-array-implementation) from Kevin Choi earlier, which had several answers which explained what to do to solve the problem.  Are you plagiarizing his code?  Are you KC under a different name?

Comment: @DSM It is probably code taken from a textbook and the assignment is to re-write it without using an array.

Comment: @eandersson: [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15734582/advice-with-a-file-program-asking-for-the-largest-number) makes it seem like KC wrote the code, but you could be right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no reason not to use an array in this case, but if you really want to do it without you could do something like this.

```
def main():
    infile = open('numbers.dat', 'r')

    largest = 0
    count = 0
    for line in infile:
        number = int(line)

        if number > largest:
            # If the number on the line we are currently reading is greater than,
            # our previously highest. Set the highest to this number instead.
            largest = number

        # Increment the number of lines we have read.
        count += 1

    infile.close()

    # Finally print the values we got from parsing the file
    print('The largest number in the file is: %s' % largest)
    print('The amount of numbers in the file is: %s' % count)
main()
```

Comment: I always thought that by implementing number = [], it means you are using a list or an array.

Comment: You are, but in this code `numbers` is never used, only `number` which is an integer. I removed the unused variable in my code to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 1):

```
def main():
    with open('numbers.dat') as infile:
        largest_num = float('-inf') # in case all your numbers are negative,
                                    # 0 can't be default
        for i, line in enumerate(infile, 1): # i is the line number
            largest_num = max(largest_num, int(line))
        print 'Largest num is: ', largest_num
        print 'num of lines is: ', i

main()
```